# pasing params["filter[limit]"] = 200 in url for WooCommerce Oauth request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, oauth-2.0, woocommerce

I am trying to pass a parameter which returns me more that 10 orders for a woocommerce API request, i am using ruby 1.9.3 and rails 2.3.18.

When i pass regular parameters and generate the url it works fine, like for example the below works fine

```
        params[:oauth_consumer_key] = @consumer_key
        params[:oauth_nonce] = Digest::SHA1.hexdigest(Time.new.to_i.to_s)
        params[:oauth_signature_method] = 'HMAC-SHA256'
        params[:oauth_timestamp] = Time.new.to_i
        params[:oauth_signature] = generate_oauth_signature(endpoint, params, method)
```

However when i try to pass a filter parameter i get error saying the now i want to pass a filter parameter like **`filter[limit]=20`**, the request does not work.

```
      I am passing the filter parameter like **`params["filter[limit]"] = 20`**, is this correct of is there any other way.
```